installing owncloud in nginx server
I'm trying to install owncloud in a nginx server. I have no idea how the config file works in nginx and im strugling alot trying to make it even display de index.php
http{
        server {
         listen 80;

         root /var/www/owncloud;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;

         location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        }

        }
}
events{}

This is my actual config file
now i get a 502 Bad Gateway error and i don't have any idea why is that
screenshotr of the error page
When i make it work during the installtion or when it finishes owncloud tryes to access the folder apps/files
and i dont know why although it exists nginx gives me a 404 error. i can't add a screenshoot of that because it doesnt work now.
